# Folder redirection, show local file paths only, not server file path

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-permissions, folder-redirection

I'm experiencing a problem with a Windows Server 2012 R2 network which has folder redirection configured. Today I have found a problem where it's possible for the user to see the full file path from the server when they try and attach files in Outlook. This fault does not occur using Windows Explorer. The server path (where the files are redirected to) is as follows

```
\\servername\Shares\Users$\Username\files
```

How can I configure the network to only show the local file path when attaching files, instead of the full location of the redirection area?

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no vulnerability here - you simply need to ensure your shares are secured properly.